# How to fetch Data of Previous date in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, mysql, sql

Kindly refer the script below.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#scirpt to connect with db

master_db_user=''
master_db_passwd=''
master_db_port='3306'
master_db_host=''
master_db_name='uppcldashboard'

Now=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")
date=$(date +"%F")


#Preparing script

#SQL_Query='select * from test_table;'

#MySql Command to connect to a database

#mysql -u$master_db_user -p$master_db_passwd -D$master_db_name -e "select * from uppcl_amount_details into outfile '/created_files/uppcl.csv' fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n';"

mysql -u$master_db_user -p$master_db_passwd -D$master_db_name -e "select *,IFNULL(ref_4,0),IFNULL(ref_3,0),IFNULL(ref_7,0),IFNULL(ref_8,0),date_format(posting_date,'%Y-%m-%d') from uppcl_amount_details where posting_date>=CURDATE() into outfile '/created_files/uppcl.csv' fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n';"

mv /created_files/uppcl.csv /created_files/offline_collection$Now.csv

sed -i "1i id","Cashier_id","Cheque_no","collection_amount","collection_type","Posting_date","Discom","Division_Code","Division_Name","Head_cashier_id","ref_3","ref_4","ref_5","ref_6","ref_7","ref_8","Tran_Date","Status","Posting_Updated_Date" /created_files/offline_collection$Now.csv
echo "End of the Script"
```

Okay, so this script basically fetches data from a MySQL server of that current date and I have to schedule this script so that it will fetch data of that current date. but here is the issue that data comes in a continuous manner so I can't just schedule it for 2 am in the morning because it will get data entered in the MySQL server till 2 am, so I thought of two work around either I get data of the previous date for eg today is 16/04/2020 so if the script run today at 2 am in the morning it will fetch data 15/04/2020.

or

I schedule this script in such a way like at the end of the day, like 11:58 pm or something like this.

In your opinion which is the best way also can you tell meh the cronjob for 11:58 pm.

if I consider getting data of the previous date then changes should be made to get that.

**Thanks and Regards,
Sagar Mandal**

Comment: cron job for 11:58 pm is [ 58 23 * * *  ] right ?

Comment: Why do you have the line `date=$(date +"%F")`? You never use it.

Comment: @nobody I used it earlier and forget to comment it. thanks for looking into my script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would in your case definitely limit the query in that way that you get records from one day no matter when the query is started. In that way, you can start it at 2am or whenever. In that way, you can run the script later manually if something went wrong at the time, when it was supposed to be executed.

In your script change the where condition to something like this:

```
where DATE(posting_date) = DATE(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY))
```

In that way, you get only record which have a date from yesterday.

If you want to do it with bash variables, get the current date in a form that is suitable for MySql:

```
date=$(date --rfc-3339=date)
```

The output for `$date` is in the form recognizable for MySql:

```
2020-04-16
```

Then make a where condition something like this:

```
where DATE(posting_date) = DATE(DATE_ADD('$date', INTERVAL -1 DAY))
```

If you change the `interval -1 day`, you can get the data for any day you want.

---

And one more thing. Do not provide usernames and passwords to MySql from scripts. In that way, passwords are revealed and sooner or later you will regret that. Use `mysql_config_editor` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-config-editor.html) to store credentials and use them later in a script like yours.

Comment: Oh my gawd buddy that's awsome i tried  "where DATE(posting_date) = DATE(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY))" and it worked completely fine. earlier I was doing this "where posting_date>=CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY" but I was getting data of current date as well.